# what am i doing wrong with ReactJS eventHandlers

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to  make suggested search entries display in from Google Api appear in the div with the id Suggested-Places using input values from the input tag with the id SearchBar. Unfortunately,the event handlers aren't firing.
here is my code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    import logo from './logo.svg';
    import './App.css';
    import MdShoppingCart from 'react-icons/lib/md/shopping-cart'

    export default class HeaderMin extends Component{
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.suggestedPlaces=[];
            this.state={
                suggestions:this.suggestedPlaces
            }
            this.userLocationInput=this.userLocationInput.bind(this);
            this.suggestedLocations=this.suggestedLocations.bind(this);
        }
        componentDidMount() {
                this.address=this.refs.inputBox.value;
                const searchBar=ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.inputBox);
                searchBar.addEventListener('keyUp keyPress keyDown',this.userLocationInput)
        }
        suggestedLocations(location){
            this.suggestedPlaces.push(location);
        }
        userLocationInput() {
            const key="&key=AIzaSyCvfy3g8ljGFtVyfCP9idWbwRo_-HASt_0",url="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=";
            let query=this.address;
            const endPoint=url+query+key;
            return fetch("http://localhost:8080/"+url+query+key)
            .then((res)=>res.json())
            .then((res)=>res.results.map((loc)=>this.suggestedLocations(loc.formatted_address)))
        }


        render(){
            return(
                <div  className="myheader header-min">
                    <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/www-mybukka-com/image/upload/v1505151382/logo_m8ik1x.png" id="logo" alt="logo"/>
                    <div className="search-box search-box-min">
                    <div>
                    <input type='text' ref="inputBox" id="SearchBar" defaultValue='search your location'/>
                    <div id="Suggested-Places">{this.state.suggestions.map((location)=><p>{location}</p>)}</div>
                    </div>
                    <button className="btn-sml btn-red"></button>
                    </div>
                    <div className="header-top-button header-top-button-min">
                    <button ></button>
                    <button className="btn-red"></button>
                    <MdShoppingCart className="shopping-cart"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                )
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can make a simpler version of this code which reproduces your problem.

Answer (score 0):

React use synthetic events, so your regular events won't probably work. Use the regular React way if you want it to work.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using Reacts built-in event handler props. Also, you can simplify your code:

```
<input type='text' ref="inputBox" id="SearchBar" defaultValue='search your location' onKeyDown={this.userLocationInput}/>
```

You probably don't need to bind the same event to all 3 key events, `onKeyDown` should be enough. If you need the other ones as well, you can use `onKeyPress` and `onKeyUp`.

EDIT:

And after looking at `userLocationInput`, you'll need to make a small change:

```
userLocationInput(e) {
    const key="&key=AIzaSyCvfy3g8ljGFtVyfCP9idWbwRo_-HASt_0",url="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=";
    let query = e.target.value; // or this.refs.textInput.value
    const endPoint=url+query+key;
    return fetch("http://localhost:8080/"+url+query+key)
    .then((res)=>res.json())
    .then((res)=>res.results.map((loc)=>this.suggestedLocations(loc.formatted_address)))
}
```

When you bind `this.address` in the `componentDidMount` to `this.refs.textInput.value`, that's a one time assignment. `this.address` won't update everytime the value gets changed. So instead you should be using `e.target.value` or `this.refs.textInput.value`.

One last note, string refs are being deprecated in React so you should be using a ref callback instead.

```
<input ref={ ref => this.textInput = ref } />
...
// Getting value from input
this.textInput.value;
```

Comment: We are binding `userLocationInput` to the `onKeyDown` event. Whenever a key is pressed down in that input, the function `userLocationInput` will be called with one parameter, e, the event. Using the event, we can get the target (the input box) and get its value.